# javascript function to accept multiple date formats

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

Users want to use the following formats to enter dates:-
mm-dd-yyyy OR yyyy-mm-dd OR  m-d-yy OR m-d-yyyy OR mm/dd/yyyy OR m/d/yy.
My plan is to capture whatever they enter and convert it to yyyy-mm-dd because that is the format that the date field value must be submitted. They have refused to use a calendar . I have tried the following JS function  without any success. Any ideas?

```
    var value = ctrl.getValue();
    var date_input = new Date(value);
    var day = date_input.getDay();
    var month = date_input.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date_input.getFullYear();
    var yyyy_MM_dd = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    return yyyy_MM_dd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because its wrong to use `var day = date_input.getDay();`

use it like this

```
var day = date_input.getDate();
```

```js
function getDateFormat(value){
  var date_input = new Date(value);
  var day = date_input.getDate();
  var month = date_input.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date_input.getFullYear();
  var yyyy_MM_dd = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  return yyyy_MM_dd;
}
console.log(getDateFormat("2017-12-30"));
console.log(getDateFormat("12-30-2017"));
```

`.getDay` is giving you days of weeks

Also be sure to use date format accepted by [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Thanks ! I have accepted your answer!  I do not think I am the one who voted you down, but I just voted you up anyway ! Have a g8 day